# Inserting unique rows into a table where not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I am using postgres 8.4.
I am merging several tables into one. There are duplicates both within and across tables. The new table will have a unique constraint. I have inserted the first table into the new big table without trouble, but when trying to add the second table I get an error. I have tried:

```
INSERT INTO big_table(id, col1, col2)
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
        id,
        col1,
        col2,
        FROM table2
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT id, col1, col2
            FROM big_table
            WHERE(big_table.id = table2.id))
```

I get the following error:

> invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "big_table" LINE
>   13: ...big_table WHERE(table2.id = big_table.id))
>
> HINT:  There is an entry for table "big_tweets", but it cannot be
>   referenced from this part of the query.

I think it might have something to do with the fact that big_table changes, but I'm not sure how else to exclude rows that already exist in the table.

Comment: Your query doesnt have `arabic_tweets`. Also you dont need `SELECT id col1 col2` with `SELECT 1` will do the same job

Comment: don't you just miss commas between `id col1 col2`?

Comment: @RadimBača I did, but just because copy/paste from OP query :P

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza man, it is message to Reen...

Comment: Oops, thanks, I fixed both. I simplified the table/column names and missed a couple.

Comment: Well if the query isnt complete, how are we suppose to know what to fix? If you have duplicated between the same table, which row will you take? Because you do `DISTINCT ID` but what happen if have different `col1, col2`

Comment: I want distinct on id, not on col1 or col2. It is okay if there are differences within col1 and col2. Having "col1" instead of a substantive name doesn't make the query incomplete, just more intelligible out of context. The error has something to do with the second where statement, not with the column names.

Comment: But to answer your question, I don't care which is taken in this context. As written, it should take the first row it comes across. If a row with that id already exists, it shouldn't try to insert.

Comment: I mean is incomplete because your query doesnt have `arabic_tweets` so the error doesnt make sense. Unless you have a triggers somewhere .

Comment: Ack! Sorry! I thought I fixed them all. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Not related to your question. But instead you can `UNION` all the table before create the big table to remove the duplicates.

```
 CREATE big_table as 
       SELECT id, col1, col2 FROM Table1
       UNION
       SELECT id, col1, col2 FROM Table2
       ....
       UNION
       SELECT id, col1, col2 FROM TableN
```

You also can use a CTE to solve the self reference problem

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
        id,
        col1,
        col2,
        FROM table2
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT id, col1, col2
            FROM big_table
            WHERE(big_table.id = table2.id))
)
INSERT INTO big_table
SELECT * 
FROM cte
```